# convert LinkedTreeMap to List while deserializing data using Gson

Tags: android, realm, gson

I am storing incoming json from server into my model class. i tried to create generalize the response class to store response of different webservices in realm db.

**Here is my response class**

```
public class TResponse<T> {    

    @Expose
    private String code;
    @Expose
    private String message;
    @Expose
    private Summary summary;
    @Expose
    private String status;
    @Expose
    private String error;

    @Expose
    private List errors;

    @Expose
    private List<T> response;

}
```

Json that i am trying to store

```
{
  "diabetes": [
    {
      "_id": "5b83a79e4297c60021cc0ee2",
      "blood_glucose": 137,
      "timestamp": "2018-07-31T09:01:48+00:00",
      "utc_offset": "+05:30",
      "last_updated": "2018-08-27T07:26:22+00:00"
    },
    {
      "_id": "5b83a79e4297c60021cc0e88",
      "blood_glucose": 140,
      "timestamp": "2018-07-31T09:01:48+00:00",
      "utc_offset": "+05:30",
      "last_updated": "2018-08-27T07:26:22+00:00"
    }
  ],
  "errors": [
    {
      "code": 409,
      "message": "Conflict",
      "errors": "Activity is already taken",
      "activity_id": "468eb4bf-0d84-4b77-bb94-daebd0063955"
    }
  ]
}
```

the diabetes array will going to store into the generalized list `List<T> response` , now in order to map the diabetes to `List<T> response` i have to map that list explicitly in deserializer and for that i am using `Gson` parser

```
 @Override
    public T deserialize(JsonElement json, Type typeOfT, JsonDeserializationContext context) throws JsonParseException {

      TResponse tResponse = new TResponse();
      tResponse.setSummary(context.deserialize(json.getAsJsonObject().get("summary"),Summary.class));
      tResponse.setResponse(context.deserialize(json.getAsJsonObject().get(mKey.toLowerCase()),List.class));
      tResponse.setErrors(context.deserialize(json.getAsJsonObject().get("errors").getAsJsonArray(),List.class));
      return  (T) tResponse;

    }
```

in above code mKey is the `Diabetes.class`

Now problem here is when am trying to create a new object of `TResponse` and storing data into it , Gson stores it as a `LinkedTreeMap` rather then the `List`

see below screenshot

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All i need to take care of parametrized class type and here i was just passing the raw class information hence parser could not figure out what is underneath the list

```
tResponse.setResponse(context.deserialize(json.getAsJsonObject().get(mKey.toLowerCase()),getType(List.class,Diabetes.class)));
```

Following is the function that takes care of the parameter class and return the appropriate `Type`

```
private Type getType(final Class<?> rawClass, final Class<?> parameterClass) {
        return new ParameterizedType() {
            @Override
            public Type[] getActualTypeArguments() {
                return new Type[]{parameterClass};
            }

            @Override
            public Type getRawType() {
                return rawClass;
            }

            @Override
            public Type getOwnerType() {
                return null;
            }

        };
    }
```